# What type of distribution is used to model random variables that change w.r.t time?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Specifically, I am thinking of something like a restaurant. Clearly the time at which people come in is still random but the rate at which people enter is going to be much higher at say 12pm than 3:30pm. I thought at first P(x | time = t) would be poisson with different means given the time but this violates the assumption that "The rate cannot be higher in some intervals and lower in other intervals." What pdf is used to model this type of behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can have Poisson distributions with different means for different intervals.  For example, the number of customers between 12 and 1 pm may be Poisson with mean 50, while the number of customers between 3 and 4 pm may be Poisson with mean 15.

If every interval of the day has a Poisson distribution with means $x_1, x_2, ...x_n$ respectively, the pdf for the day would be Poisson with mean $\sum_{i=1}^n x_1$ since the sum of independent Poisson variables is also Poisson.

Comment: That was my initial thinking as well, but consider this, the pdf for the time between 12-4 would be ~ poisson (50+15), clearly this is untrue, by the properties of a poisson distribution, the mean over any half the interval would be (50+15/2). Additionally, arrivals would be evenly spaced and not clumped up at times as they would be in real life.

Comment: @BenjaminWhitesell  If I'm correct, that which you mention that the mean over half of an interval has half of the mean of the interval is only true **if** the Poisson has a constant rate across the interval.  But I don't think this has to be true for every Poisson.  For example, if the number of customers in a restaurant per day has pdf Poisson(200), that means the # of customers that come from 12am-11:59pm is Poisson(200). Yet, the number of customers from 3-4am would not be Poisson(200/24). (It would actually be Poisson(0).)  This does not mean that the daily distribution can't be Poisson.

Comment: Can you have a poisson distribution that doesn't have a constant rate across the interval? Is that a well defined concept?

Comment: It seems to me that you can, but I can't say I've never been wrong before.  Do you have reason to believe otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be a locally integrable function (that is, $\int_K \lambda<\infty$ for all compact sets in $[0,\infty)$. Define $$\Lambda(t)=\int_0^t \lambda(s)\ \mathsf ds. $$ Let $\{N(t):t\geqslant 0\}$ be a counting process, i.e. $N(0)=0$, $N(t)$ is nonnegative integer-valued, and $N(t)$ is nondecreasing ($0\leqslant s\leqslant t$ implies $N(s)\leqslant N(t)$) such that $$N(t)-N(s)\sim\mathsf{Pois}(\Lambda(t)-\Lambda(s))$$ for $0\leqslant s<t$. Then 
$$\mathbb P(N(s,t]=k)=\frac{[\Lambda(t)-\Lambda(s)]^k}{k!} $$ and $N(t)$ is a nonhomogeneous Poisson process with intensity function $\lambda$.

This is the most natural way to model an arrival process with a time-varying arrival rate.